# Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document Internal Exception:

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Estoy haciendo un script en PHP para registrar los títulos electrónicos en el servicio que nos da la SEP, hasta ahora se han realizado de manera manual sin ningún problema (*ingresando a la URL y cargando la información usando la extensión de chrome Wizdler, según indicaciones de la propia SEP*), si la operación se hace desde el script, funciona correctamente, pero el servidor siempre arroja error en la respuesta:

```
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'P' (code 80) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]"
```

Incluso con exactamente los mismos datos que de manera manual funcionaron correctamente.

Este es mi código:

```
$usuario = 'usuario';
$password = 'contraseña';
$archivo = '10000.xml';
$handle = fopen($archivo, "r");
$data = '';
while(!feof($handle)){
    $data .= fread($handle, filesize($archivo));
}
fclose($handle);
$b64 = trim(base64_encode($data));
$response = NULL;
$params = ["nombreArchivo" => $archivo, "archivoBase64" => $b64, "autenticacion" => ["usuario" => $usuario, "password" => $password ] ] ;
try {
        $client = new SoapClient($url);
        $response = $client->cargaTituloElectronico( ["nombreArchivo" => $archivo, "archivoBase64" => $b64, "autenticacion" => ["usuario" => $usuario, "password" => $password ] ] );
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
        echo "SOAPFault: ".$fault->faultcode."-".$fault->faultstring."\n";
        exit();
}
$lote = $response->numeroLote;
$mensaje = $response->mensaje;
try{
    $response2 = $client->descargaTituloElectronico( ["numeroLote" => $lote, "autenticacion" => ["usuario" => $usuario, "password" => $password ] ] );
} catch ( SoapFault $e ){
    echo "SOAPFault: ".$fault->faultcode."-".$fault->faultstring."\n";
    exit();
}
if (isset($response2->titulosBase64)){
    $archivoZip = 'ResultadoCargaTitulos_'.$lote.'.zip';
    $mensaje = $response2->mensaje;
    $titulosBase64 = $response2->titulosBase64;
    $file = fopen($archivoZip, 'w');
    fwrite($file, $titulosBase64);
    fclose($file);
    var_dump($mensaje);
}else{
    echo "no se encontró archivo de respuesta.";
    var_dump($mensaje);
}
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Tal vez podría indicar en qué línea arroja el error. Luego aclarar conceptos más detallados de lo que deseas realizar. Y qué significa que __si la operación se hace desde el script, funciona correctamente, pero el servidor siempre arroja error en la respuesta__ Significa que funciona o que no funciona?

Comment: Gracias, el código no da ningún error. Si el envió de datos al servicio se realiza correctamente, se obtiene un archivo en formato excel con el resultado de la operación. Cuando se realiza en el navegador con la extensión Wizdler, el resultado es satisfactorio, pero si se realiza por medio del script PHP el servicio indica **"Unexpected character 'P' (code 80) in prolog"** en el archivo excel de respuesta.

Comment: Hola, pudiste resolverlo? Tengo el mismo error, lo único que he visto es que desde mi script php el resultado en base64 que genera al consumir el método descargaTituloElectronico en <titulosBase64></titulosBase64> es diferente al que se genera desde wizdler o programas como soapUI siendo el de estos 2 ultimos correcto y el mio no, leyendo la poca información de la api no se si tenga que ver con que se debe contar con la llave de encriptación debidamente instalada y disponible por la aplicación cliente para poder invocar los WS de manera segura a través del protocolo HTTPS